# Will this test to check if an element has an attribute work?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
hasAttr = new function(tag, attrName) {
    return (tag.attrName)
}
```

Will this code work? I can't test it now because I cannot acces [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) but [Down For Everyone or Just Me?](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/) says something else.

1. [jsFiddle Down For Everyone or Just Me](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/jsfiddle.net)
2. [jsBin Down For Everyone or Just Me](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/jsbin.com)

Example usage:

JavaScript:

```
alert(hasAttr("div", "id"))
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

Expected:

```
(In alert box)
    true
                OK
```

Can someone test it for me?

If it doesn't work, how should I code it?

I want `hasAttr` to return `true` or `false`.

I will be open to code optimization, cleaner code etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `hasAttr("div", "id")` You are sending a string "div" and you are treating it like an object in your function. Something is wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if an HTML element has an attribute, you should use [`hasAttribute`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t125). If you have to support IE6 and IE7, check its existence using [`[name]`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t127).

Given that, the implementation of `hasAttr` would be something like this:

```
hasAttr = function(tag, attrName) {
    return tag.hasAttribute ? tag.hasAttribute(attrName)
                            : tag[attrName] !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite using `if` instead of `?`/`:` please?

Comment: `return a ? b : c` means `if(a) { return b; } else { return c; }`.

Comment: Why the `new` here?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Good catch, I don't think it belongs there. It was in the original code but looks like a bug, so I edited it out of my post.

Comment: !!tag[attrName] will return false if the attribute exists but is an empty string...

Comment: @Brett You are correct that this method is blind to the difference between an attribute not existing and an attribute being `''`. But in old IE (versions 5-7 that lack `hasAttribute`), `getAttribute` returns `null` when the attribute is not defined. So doing `function hasAttr(el, attr) { return el.hasAttribute ? el.hasAttribute(attr) : el.getAttribute(attr) !== null; }` should work. Tested using http://netrenderer.com/index.php.

Answer (score 2):

Testing JavaScript code in jsFiddle to make sure it works is suicide. The difficult part about JavaScript is really cross-browser compatibility, which means you just **can't** just test in one browser to say it works.

That being said, the name `hasAttr` makes me think that you want to return true/false, which is not what you're doing. You should use DOM's [`element.hasAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.hasAttribute), which already implements what you're trying to do. It's DOM 1, so it's safe to use and will work in any browser supporting JavaScript.

By the way, why are you using this funky syntax to create your function? Is there a good reason not to use `function hasAttribute() { ... }`?

(You should accept seand's answer, though, I didn't know it wasn't supported until IE 8. You should also consider using something like jQuery which will help you avoid mistakes like that.)

Comment: you beat me by ~20 seconds :)

Comment: Not really the same answer! I didn't know about IE, and you didn't notice he wants to see "true", which means he simply wants hasAttribute. At least I think so.

Comment: Ah, good catch, thanks... changed my answer.